# Meter reading system

Tags: java

I'm designing a program for printing out a single telephone telephone pin. The program should including
 1. Name of the customer 
2.Address of the customer
 3. Telephone number
 4. Previous meter reading 
5. Current meter reading.

The program will also include the number of units consumed, and print the bill charge using the following....

if my consumed unit is a negative, it doesn't show no cost... How do i go about this?

System.out.println("Enter Current reading");
    cread=input.nextInt(); //get integer input and store it in Current reading

```
input.close();

int unit= (pread - cread);
System.out.println("Your Consumed unit is " + unit);

if (unit >= 0 && unit <= 100) {
    System.out.println("Your cost is 2.50");

}
else if (unit >= 100 && unit <= 200) {
    System.out.println("Your cost is 2.25");
}
else if (unit >= 200 && unit <=300) {
    System.out.println("Your cost is 1.90");
}
if (unit >= 300) {
    System.out.println("Your cost is 1.65");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Such as the kind of value you expect to be inputted with regards to the meter reading?

Comment: The program will calculate the number of units consume, and complete the bill charge using the following rates.... 1.( >0 and <=100) is 2.50 2.( >100 and <=200) is 2.25 3. (> 200 and <=300) is 1.90 4. ( >100) is 1.65....

Comment: @Netherland ,That you can do.Consumed units=new reading-old reading and then calculate the bill charge

Comment: @Netherland - You really should edit that information into the question.  And also, it's best if you actually ASK a question, rather than just saying "I'm stuck".  Otherwise, it's impossible to know what help to give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another input prompt an store it in new variables.Here is the improved code with all changes explained in the comments in the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BillingSystem {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare variables

    String name,addr;
    int pread, cread,tel; //New variables here

    // input

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Customer Name");
    name= input.nextLine();

    //Scanner address = new Scanner (System.in); no need for this
    System.out.println("Address of The Customer");
    addr= input.nextLine();

    //Scanner telephone = new Scanner (System.in); no need for this
    System.out.println("Enter telephone number");
    tel=input.nextInt(); //get integer input and store it in tel

    System.out.println("Enter Previous reading");
    pread=input.nextInt(); //get integer input and store it in pread

    System.out.println("Enter Current reading");
    cread=input.nextInt(); //get integer input and store it in cread



 }
}
```

Comment: input.close();
    
    int unit= (pread - cread);
    System.out.println("Your Consumed unit is " + unit);
    
    if (unit >= 0 && unit <= 100) {
     System.out.println("Your cost is 2.50");
     
    }
    else if (unit >= 100 && unit <= 200) {
     System.out.println("Your cost is 2.25");
    }
    else if (unit >= 200 && unit <=300) {
     System.out.println("Your cost is 1.90");
    }
    if (unit >= 300) {
     System.out.println("Your cost is 1.65");
    }
    





 }

}

Comment: @Netherland , No.You'll get 2.50 as the cost. BTW,how come that as the consumed unit increases,the cost decreases??

Comment: That's a great question, i have no clue... i will definitely ask the lec on Monday..... If my pread is 200 and my cread is 300, why am i not getting a cost per unit but im getting a consumed unit -100....

Comment: I have the program running:)